# How to execute node.js protoype function from html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, gpio

I have a program that will work to start a motion sensor when running the file from the command line, but when I try to call the function from HTML, it recognizes the prototype as 'undefined' and will not execute.

Here is the full code:

```
var sleep = require('sleep'); 
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio; 
var LED = new Gpio(18, 'out');
var sensor = new Gpio(17, 'in', 'both'); 

sensor.watch(function(err, value){ 
if (err){
    console.log('error');
    exit();
}
if(value == 1) {  
    console.log('Motion Detected');
    LED.writeSync(value); 
    sleep.sleep(3); 
}
else if(value == 0) {
    console.log('No Motion');
    LED.writeSync(value);  
    sleep.sleep(3);
}
});

function exit() {
LED.unexport();
sensor.unexport();
process.exit();
}
```

dev tools says 'sensor' is undefined.

How do I run sensor.watch(callback) from html?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your HTML so we can see how you're including this script and calling the function?

Comment: abbreviated: 
<button onclick="sensor.watch()">
...
<script src="../modules/motionSensor.js"></script>

but admittedly all I've ever called from html looks more like 

function fnName () {
    console.log('hi);
}